# Putting display to sleep using windows keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

Is there some key combination to put the display on a mac to sleep using a windows keyboard, or somewhere where I can change the default key combinations?

Answer (score 2):

function-win-shift-f12 (if you have hotkeys turned off where function keys act as normal function keys)
otherwise, 
win-shift-f12

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise hot corners on mission control, indeed it's quite handy for putting monitor on sleep or show desktop.

Simply you can attribute a corner of your screen to put on sleeping your monitor (by mouse pointer though, not with your keyboard, If you are using mouse/trackpad)

To activate this on your mac:

preferences > mission control > hot corners

You will see four corners and many options for each corners.

Comment: I came across somewhere that you can use hot-corners and require holding down the cmd key for it to work, but I can't find anything explaining how to make this change, any idea?
With hot corners alone I keep doing it by accident.

Comment: @CorneliusJEhmke i think you can do it simply by: choose a hot corner action from drop down menu while you are pressing a shortcut you wish to make the combination.

Comment: That's worked, thanks. but it's having a bit of a freakout about the peripherals attached to it now.. :P these things are such a nuisance